# How do I improve remove duplicate algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm

My interview question was that I need to return the length of an array that removed duplicates but we can leave at most 2 duplicates.

For example, `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]` the new array would be `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3]`. So the new length would be 5. I came up with an algorithm with O(2n) I believe. How can I improve that to be the fastest.

```
def removeDuplicates(nums):
    if nums is None:
        return 0

    if len(nums) == 0:
        return 0

    if len(nums) == 1:
        return 1

    new_array = {}
    for num in nums:
        new_array[num] = new_array.get(num, 0) + 1

    new_length = 0
    for key in new_array:
        if new_array[key] > 2:
            new_length = new_length + 2
        else:
            new_length = new_length + new_array[key]

    return new_length

new_length = removeDuplicates([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3])
assert new_length == 5
```

My first question would be is my algorithm even correct?

Comment: use `Counter` or `dict`

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Code Review only accepts code that *works as intended* - the question at the bottom of this post would probably need to be reworded a bit to avoid attracting "unclear what you're asking" or "broken code" close votes.

Comment: O(2n) = O(n), and you can't do better than this since you have to read the entire array.  If you are looking for a constant-time speedup, consider [profiling](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html).

Comment: Your code looks about as good as it can get to me.

Comment: You can 'leave at most 2 duplicates' meaning you can have zero duplicates right? So why not `list(set([1,1,1,2,2,3]))`? Should be O(n) too but simpler

Comment: @user2341963 What he means is that it should count up to 2 duplicates. So the result should be `2 + 2 + 1` because there are more than 2 1's, 2 2's, and 1 3.

Comment: [Cross-posted on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/97194/23788)

Comment: `sum(min(2, count) for count in collections.Counter(nums).values())`

Comment: Is this "up to two instances of every value", "unique values but for two exceptions at most", or "unique values but for up to two values occurring twice"? Are the values in the input array specified to be grouped?

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is correct however he is a simpler method to reach the goal you had mentioned in your question.

Here is my logic.

```
myl = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]

newl = []

for i in myl:
    if newl.count(i) != 2:
        newl.append(i)

print newl
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't see this returning anything, and it prints something not asked for.

Comment: The objective of the exercise was to remove any occurrence of an item if that item occurred more than twice in a list. The example I had given in my answer works just fine to answer @toy's question. 

The output is pasted directly from a python IDE.

Comment: `I need to return the length of an array`

Comment: `len(newl)` should do. The idea was to suggest a viable alternative solution. He knew how to extract the length of an array.

Answer (score 1):

If your original array size is `n`.

1. Count distinct numbers in your array.
2. If you have `d` distinct numbers, then your answer will be

   ```
    d        (when n == d)
    d+1      (when n == d+1)
    d+2      (when n >= d+2)
   ```

If all the numbers in your array are less than `n-1`, you can even solve this without using any extra space. If that's the case check [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-duplicates-in-on-time-and-constant-extra-space/) and you can count distinct numbers very easily without using extra space.

Comment: Depending on the interpretation of `duplicate`. (If all numbers are unique but one occurring thrice, at least, is `d+1` correct, `d+2`, both or none?)

Answer (score 1):

I'd forget about generating the new array and just focus on counting:

```
from collections import Counter

def count_non_2dups(nums):
    new_len = 0
    for num, count in Counter(nums).items():
        new_len += min(2, count)
    return new_len
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int removeDuplicates(vector<int>& nums) {
    if (nums.size() == 0) return nums.size();
    int state = 1;
    int idx = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
        if (nums[i] != nums[i-1]) {
            state = 1;
            nums[idx++] = nums[i];
        }
        else if (state == 1) {
            state++;
            nums[idx++] = nums[i];
        }
        else {
            state++;
        }
    }
    return idx;
}
```

idea:maintain a variable(state) recording the current repeat times(more precisely, state records the repeat times of the element which adjacent to the left of current element). This algorithm is O(n) with one scanning of the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
def removeDuplicates(nums):
    if nums is None:
        return 0

    if len(nums) == 0:
        return 0

    if len(nums) == 1:
        return 1

    new_array_a = set()
    new_array_b = set()
    while nums:
        i = nums.pop()
        if i not in new_array_a:
            new_array_a.add(i)
        elif i not in new_array_b:
            new_array_b.add(i)

    return len(new_array_a) + len(new_array_b)
```